# Need help identifiying identity to use

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{{n \choose i}(-1)^n}{i+1}$$

I rearranged terms so that I get

$$n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{(i+1)!(n-i)!}$$

and then looked at the partial sums but I am not able to get anywhere with this. I could use some advice.

Comment: Surround your code in \$'s or \$\$'s

Comment: Should that be $(-1)^{\color{Red}{i}}$ in the numerator?

Answer (score 1):

We have the binomial expansion:
$$
(1-x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}(-1)^i x^i,
$$
and hence
$$
\int_0^1(1-x)^n\,dx=\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}(-1)^i \int_0^1x^i\,dx=
\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}(-1)^i \frac{1}{i+1}.
$$
Thus
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{{n \choose i}(-1)^i}{i+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$